# Ввод в одну строку в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, for

У меня есть строка:

```
number = int(input('Введите количество'))
```

Как сделать так, чтобы если пишут например **`2`**,

```
a, b = map(int, input().split())
```

А если пишут **`3`**,

```
a, b, c = map(int, input().split())
```

Иными словами, если пишут **`100`**, то в строке записывалось **`100`** переменных?

Comment: Зачем вам 100 переменных? Чем не устроил list?

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что если написали 3, то чтобы шёл запрос на ввод 3 чисел

Comment: `input().split()` и так возвращает любое количество чисел. Если вам нужно проверить, что чисел ровно 3, всегда можно сделать len() и отпечатать ошибку при несовпадении. Зачем здесь 100 переменных, по-прежнему непонятно

Answer (score 4):

```
[ int(input("Введите {} число: ".format(i+1)))  for i in range(0, int(input("Введите количество переменных: ")))]

Введите количество переменных: 5
Введите 1 число: 12
Введите 2 число: 12
Введите 3 число: 122
Введите 4 число: 1
Введите 5 число: 55

[12, 12, 122, 1, 55]
```